# New standard field "Description"

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In various content elements, a new field is inserted under TYPO3 7.6 LTS, ie description.
Which function of this field is provided? Is it an internal comment field or has additional amount of duties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is for internal usage (so you might abuse it), where you can comment on the content element. This field is shown as description in the BE only.

Answer (score 2):

The "description" is an Internal Comment field.

Its Best Practice for Editor to Put in some Comment. This Comment is visible in the Backend even Without editign the Content Element.
This especialliy usefull if you have a complicated Site. because its not always clear what a certain plugin does on this page. or Why a certain content element has some Restricted access, Or you might just note that this content "element" is refered on some other page and you should be corefull with modifing/deleting it.